# Find Pythagorean Triple with Perimeter == 24

Tags: scala

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) gives this [exercise](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension):

> Here's a problem that combines tuples and list comprehensions: which
>   right triangle that has integers for all sides and all sides equal to
>   or smaller than 10 has a perimeter of 24? First, let's try generating
>   all triangles with sides equal to or smaller than 10:

Here's my solution in Scala. Note that I'm ignoring the right triangle part.

```
val a = List.range(1,11)
val b = List.range(1,11)
val c = List.range(1,11)

def sumsEqualsTo24(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = 
                           if(x + y + z == 24) Some( (x,y,z) ) else None

def pythagTriple(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = { 
                             if( Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) == Math.pow(z, 2) )
                                  Some( (x,y,z) ) 
                             else None
}
```

**Using flatMap**

```
val xs: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = a.flatMap(x => 
                                 b.flatMap(y => 
                                  c.flatMap(z => sumsEqualsTo24(x, y, z) ) ) )                                   

val ys: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = xs.flatMap{a => pythagTriple(a._1, a._2, a._3)}
```

**Using for-comprehension**

```
for {
  a <- List.range(1, 11)
  b <- List.range(1, 11)
  c <- List.range(1, 11) 
  xs <- sumsEqualsTo24(a,b,c)
  _ <- pythagTriplebar(xs._1, xs._2, xs._3)
} yield (a,b,c)
```

Could you please critique my code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `List`s `a`,`b`, and `c`, only one of them is needed.

So the flatmap could just use `a` three times:

```
a.flatMap(x => 
  a.flatMap(y => 
    a.flatMap(z => sumsEqualsTo24(x, y, z))))
```

For comprehensions can use extractors as you would in pattern matching or declaring a val.
You may find this more readable:

```
  ...
  c <- List.range(1, 11) 
  (x,y,z) <- sumsEqualsTo24(a,b,c)
  _ <- pythagTriplebar(x,y,z)
} yield (a,b,c)
```

Likewise you can have

```
val ys = xs.flatMap{case (x,y,z) => pythagTriple(x,y,z)}
```